# Python-Compare two string columns in same dataframe, return matching result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, matching

I have a single dataframe that has two string state columns: State and STATE_ALPHA, that I want to only return if the two columns match. Both columns are two-character strings (AK, CA, FL) and I know what the expected result should be. Thanks for your help.

I have tried these below:

```
 df10=df9['State']==['STATE_ALPHA']
```

error I receive: Arrays were different lengths: 706 vs 1

```
 df10=df9['State']=['STATE_ALPHA']
```

error I receive:Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: `df10=df9['State']==df9['STATE_ALPHA']`

Comment: `df9['State']==df9['STATE_ALPHA']`

Comment: These do not return matching rows, but it does not give me an error.

Comment: It will not give an error as the length is the same but will return a boolean series which you could use for filtering. see my answer below

Comment: I posted a solution to my question. We were very close.

Answer (score 3):

This solution works perfectly for what I need. Thanks for your help.

```
df8 = df7[df7['State'] == df7['STATE_ALPHA']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"string1":['CA','MI','AZ','NY'],"string2":['CA','MA','FL','NY']})

df_common=df[df[["string1","string2"]].apply(lambda x : x[0]==x[1],axis=1)].reset_index(drop=True).copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using input example from @Veera

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"string1":['CA','MI','AZ','NY'],"string2":['CA','MA','FL','NY']})
df[df.string1==df.string2]
string1 string2
0   CA  CA
3   NY  NY
```